# Is there any DPDK package for Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, drivers, package-management

`DPDK` is a set of libraries and drivers for fast packet processing. The common method for installing it is compiling from the source code. Is there any `.deb` package to install this library in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a package but as you can see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dpdk&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), the package is for Ubuntu 16.04 and later. You can install it using `apt-get` command as follow:

```
apt-get install dpdk
```

For older versions of Ubuntu you should download DPDK source and compile it like other Linux distributions.

See [this](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/05/05/the-new-simplicity-to-consume-dpdk/) for more information about DPDK package in Ubuntu 16.04 and later.

Comment: I installed a fresh ubuntu 16.04 and got this error: `E: Unable to locate package dpdk` . hmm, i think my iso is broken!

Comment: Refresh index file of your Ubuntu box using `apt-get update` command.

Comment: Thanks SuB for the fast answe. rIMHO  "other versions of Ubuntu" should be called "older versions", as there are newer DPDK versions in newer Ubuntu Releases. Thanks for linking the blog, it is a good start as there are more dpdk related packages (see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpdk  than just the dpdk package itself that you need dependeing what you want to do with it.